# Definition of exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

I'm learning about the exterior derivative from Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds*.

On pg. 38, the exterior derivative for a $k$-form $w$ is defined as:

For $k\geq1$, if $w=\sum_I a_Idx^I$, then
$$dw=\sum_I da_I \wedge dx^I=\sum_I(\sum_j\frac{\partial a_I}{\partial x^j}dx^j)\wedge dx^I$$
where $I$ is the multi-index notation $(i_1,...,i_k)$ and $1\leq i_1 <...<i_k\leq n$.

But on pg. 40, while trying to prove $d^2=0$, the following step was written:
$$d^2(fdx^I)=d(\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i\wedge dx^I)=\sum \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}dx^j\wedge dx^i \wedge dx^J$$
where $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function.

I don't understand how the second exterior derivative is performed. To use the definition of the exterior derivative, we need to make sure that $\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i\wedge dx^I$ is in the form $\sum_I a_Idx^I$, where the multi-index $I$ is in ascending order. How can we be sure that $dx^i\wedge dx^I$ when combined has the index in ascending order, i.e. $i <I$?

Comment: The definition of the exterior derivative that you provided also works if indices in $I$ are not in the ascending order. This follows from the skew-symmetricity of the wedge product.

Comment: In fact $d( dx_2\wedge dx_1)= d(-dx_1\wedge dx_2)=0$, as $d(-1)=0$